# High CPU of kworker/3:3+events (due to intel gpu drivers?)

Tags: cpu-usage, perf

I have a fresh install of ubuntu server 23.04 and I can see that CPU usage on idle is quite high (~0.5) after further investigation I saw that kworker proces periodically (something like every ~20sec kicks in and takes 100% of single core.
After running `sudo perf record -g -a sleep 10` I think I see that see that the issue lies in the intel drivers (intel_hdmi_detect and later), as seen on the screenshot [perf screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UxEh.png) the problem is that I don't really know how to proceed with this, what should I do?

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core 4-core Desktop Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake S] (rev 08)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 08)
00:02.0 Display controller: Intel Corporation CoffeeLake-S GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:16.1 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device a361 (rev 10)
00:16.4 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller #2 (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #17 (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #10 (rev f0)
00:1d.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #11 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO UART Host Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP LPC Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27500 Family [ConnectX-3]
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller 980
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
05:00.0 PCI bridge: ASPEED Technology, Inc. AST1150 PCI-to-PCI Bridge (rev 04)
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ASPEED Technology, Inc. ASPEED Graphics Family (rev 41)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)


$ sudo dmidecode -t 2
# dmidecode 3.4
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.2.0 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
        Manufacturer: ASRockRack
        Product Name: E3C246D4U
        Version:                       
        Serial Number: 111111111111111
        Asset Tag:                       
        Features:
                Board is a hosting board
                Board is replaceable
        Location In Chassis:                       
        Chassis Handle: 0x0003
        Type: Motherboard
        Contained Object Handles: 0
```